# ConstraintLayout equally spacing for each elements in android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have below code for equally spaced circles and in-between progress bar for connectivity, I'm not getting equally space for each circles from below code, please anybody help me with this.. I need to display equally spaced circles, there is no margin specified then also start and end space is there

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spb_followup">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="30"
            android:progressTint="@color/red"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.166"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Any help much appreciated, please help me i'm struck with this

Comment: Horizontally Chain them all.. Added chain style spread.. This should help https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your layout like below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spb_followup">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="30"
    android:progressTint="@color/red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Aug"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Aug"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Aug"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Aug"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Aug"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Aug"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Aug"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

There were some issues in your layout that I corrected. One was removing the wrong bounds you had created between views, so some views had more than 4 bounds which is pretty confusing. I also added the two attributes below:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
```

They help views spread with equal distance across the layout width.

Comment: Sorry late reply.. Yes its working perfect.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the LinearLayout for listing the circles horizontally. Try this code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spb_followup"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="30"
        android:progressTint="@color/bt_error_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/content_circles"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/content_circles"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_circles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dashed_circle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dashed_circle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dashed_circle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.166"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dashed_circle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dashed_circle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dashed_circle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dashed_circle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Aug"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar show me the whole layout code